# tf.test.is_gpu_available()) возвращает False

Tags: python, windows-10, tensorflow, keras, cuda

```
print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
```

Возвращает

```
False
True
```

Tensorflow - 2.7.0
CUDA - 11.2

Что я сделал не так? Помогите

Comment: Какая ОС, какие видеодрайвера?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну значит не видит почему-то видеокарту собственно. Какая видеокарта тоже уточните на всякий.

Comment: OS - Windows 10, видеокарта - NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1060 6GB

Comment: Драйвера - 496.13

Comment: Я только что вспомнил что раньше я устанавливал другую версию CUDA - 11.5 и потом я его удалил, но с помощью команды nvidia-smi мне выдает что версия CUDA - осталась 11.5, а при помощью другой команды ncc --version выдает что версия CUDA - 11.2 и как удалить полностью 11.5 или это не имеет значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следуйте [гайду по установке Tensorflow + GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)

> **Software requirements**
>
> The following NVIDIA® software must be installed on your system:
>
> - NVIDIA® GPU drivers —CUDA® 11.2 requires 450.80.02 or higher.
> - CUDA® Toolkit —TensorFlow supports CUDA® 11.2 (TensorFlow >= 2.5.0)
> - CUPTI ships with the CUDA® Toolkit.
> - cuDNN SDK 8.1.0 cuDNN versions). (Optional) TensorRT 7 to improve latency and throughput for inference on some models.

---

> ### Windows setup

> See the hardware requirements and software requirements listed above. Read the CUDA® install guide for Windows.
>
> Make sure the installed NVIDIA software packages match the versions
> listed above. In particular, TensorFlow will not load without the
> cuDNN64_8.dll file. To use a different version, see the Windows build
> from source guide.
>
> Add the CUDA®, CUPTI, and cuDNN installation directories to the %PATH%
> environmental variable. For example, if the CUDA® Toolkit is installed
> to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0 and cuDNN
> to C:\tools\cuda, update your %PATH% to match:

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\extras\CUPTI\lib64;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\include;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: СПАСИБО!!! Все таки не проверил наличие файла  cuDNN64_8.dll